# prepareForSegue fails when [detailviewcontroller setObject] is called

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        ListViewCell *cell = (ListViewCell *)sender;
        Category *category = cell.Category;
        NSLog(@"cell category = %@", cell.Category.Name);
        //[detailViewController setCategory:category];
        detailViewController.Category = category;
    }
}
```

NSLog clearly shows the correct cell.Category.Name, so the Category object is good.

But it fails on this line

```
detailViewController.Category = category;
```

It immediatly stops at the following line with error 'Thread 1 Program received signal sigabrt'

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

old code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        ListViewCell *cell = (ListViewCell *)sender;
        Category *category = cell.Category;
        NSLog(@"cell category = %@", cell.Category.Name);
        //[detailViewController setCategory:category];
        detailViewController.Category = category;
    }
}
```

new code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        DetailTabViewController *detailTabViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        ListViewCell *cell = (ListViewCell *)sender;
        Category *category = cell.Category;
        NSLog(@"cell category = %@", cell.Category.Name);
        //[detailViewController setCategory:category];
        detailTabViewController = category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the object in `detailViewController` does not understand the message `setCategory:`.  There should be error messages in your debug console to this effect.  If not, post the messages that *are* in your debug console.

By the way, you should not start property names (or method names) with capital letters.  It's confusing.

Comment: This is what I see in the debug console
[UITabBarController setCategory:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a100a0. I'll change the property name to lowercase, somehow I feel comfortable with first letter caps

Comment: So `detailViewController` points to a `UITabBarController`, and `UITabBarController` does not have a category property or a `setCategory:` method.  Maybe your segue has the wrong destination.

Comment: This is the first time I am creating an app using the integrated interface builder. My intention was to open a TabBarController when a tableviewcell is selected. It shows the TabBar views fine but not passing the objects. I even created a viewcontroller which inherits UITabBarController and added the Category object there but still I get the same error.

Comment: I found the issue. I created the detailTabViewController but I was still calling the detailViewController, my bad. It works now.